# Custom pattern layout

Tags: java, regex, random, pattern-matching, string-formatting

I want to generate a string according to given pattern. Let's suppose:

- `%i` denotes for incremental number
- `%.3r` denotes for a random number with 3 characters
- `%dd` denotes current day
- `%mm` denotes current month
- `%yyyy` denotes current year

Then, for example

```
IBM_%.3r => IBM_233, IBM_765..
ID_%i => ID_0, ID_1, ID_2...
%dd/%mm/%yyyy => 14/03/2014
%dd%mm%yyyy_interface.log => 14022014_interface.log
```

Please let me know whether there are any existing java library for this. Otherwise, what is the correct way to implement this ?

Comment: There is no off the shelf library to do this for you that I know of. What have you tried so far? Are these all of the artefacts you would like to be able to insert into a string? What have you tried so far?

Comment: All my search for such library has gone in vain. Secondly, no those are only the  most important artifacts that i want to insert to a string. There can be many. Moreover, %i and %r etc.. are sample conversion characters. I don't mind having any letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge there is no such libraries exist .

But you can use this code instead :

**CODE**

```
  public class RegexText {
  static int i=0;
  public static void main(String[] args) {   
      String lines[]={"IBM_%.3r", "ID_%i","%dd/%mm/%yyyy","%dd%mm%yyyy_interface_%i_%i.log","ID_%i"};     
      for(String line: lines){
          System.out.println(randomGenerate(line));
      }
   }

   public static boolean matches(String line, String regex){
       return line.matches(".*"+Pattern.quote(regex)+".*");    
   }
   public static String  randomGenerate(String line){
       Date date=new Date();
       int day=date.getDate();
       int month=date.getMonth()+1;
       int year=date.getYear()+1900;   
       while(matches(line, "%i"))
           line=line.replaceFirst("%i",""+(i++));
       while(matches(line, "%.3r"))
           line=line.replaceFirst("%.3r",""+gen3DigitRand());     
       line=line.replaceAll("%dd",""+to2Digit(day));
       line=line.replaceAll("%mm",""+to2Digit(month));
       line=line.replaceAll("%yyyy",""+year);      
       return line;

   }

   public static int gen3DigitRand(){
       int num=0;
       while(String.valueOf(num).length()!=3)          
           num=(int) (Math.random()*1000);
       return num;
   }
   public static String to2Digit(int num){
       if(num<10)
           return "0"+num;
       return num+"";

   }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
IBM_904
ID_0
14/02/2014
14022014_interface_1_2.log
ID_3
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sujith. This is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

[RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) from Apache Commons has methods to generate different Strings of a given length:

```
static String   random(int count, String chars)
static String   randomAlphabetic(int count)
static String   randomAlphanumeric(int count)
static String   randomAscii(int count)
static String   randomNumeric(int count)
```

You can use it in combination with [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)